# how to select last two child inside div which is in loop and not to give that selected child a border

Tags: html, select

```html
<div class="row news-low3">
    <?php foreach ($lowPriorityNews as $key => $news): ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">
            <div class="news-lows3">
                <h5><?php echo substr($news->title, 0, 45);
                    echo strlen($news->title) > 45 ? '...' : ''; ?></h5>
                <p class="general-info">
                    <small>
                        <li class="fa fa-clock-o ">&nbsp; <?php
                            $time = $news->news_date;
                            $myTimeStamp = strtotime($time);
                            echo date("d M Y", $myTimeStamp);
                            ?></li>
                    </small>
                    <strong class="text-warning ">| Nepal </strong>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if ($key === 5) break; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

### i dont wan to give border-bottom to last 2 child.

### the for loop runs for 6 times the op looks like :

Oddball particles tunneling through Earth cou...
  29 Sep 2018 | Nepal

Steps to Becoming a Successful Business Owner
26 Sep 2018 | Nepal

News title1
29 Sep 2018 | Nepal

News title2
26 Sep 2018 | Nepal

Quia occaecat illo velit ut id quis est corru...
23 Oct 2018 | Nepal

Facere enim necessitatibus assumenda non a la...
  24 Oct 2018 | Nepal

Comment: selecting with css I assume? you might want to add a css tag if you're looking for answers in css.

Comment: I tried this code :
 .news-lows3:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
but it gives border to all child

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-last-child` to select the last 2 rows and then remove the border:

```css
.news-low3.row > div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;        /* add border to all divs */
}

.news-low3.row > div:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  border-bottom: 0;                      /* remove border from last 2 divs */
}
```

```html
<div class="row news-low3">
  <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">should have a border</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">should have a border</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">should have a border</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">should have a border</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">should not have a border</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 news-childs">should not have a border</div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry sir, this above code doesn't work . When i try this one : 
.news-lows3:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
but it gives border to all child. What is the problem behind this code?

Comment: @lathhik if you run his code snippet you can see the css does work fine on its own, do you have other CSS already applied which may be interfering?

Comment: yah theres a lot of codes in the style.css. But theres no any css for the 'news-low3' excpet  : .news-low3{margin-bottom:20px}.

Comment: @lathhik you need to take the border off the bottom of the last 2 not add it